# In sym. group $S_3$, why is $(1,2)^{-1}=(1,2)$ and not $(2,1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Why are the inverses of 2-cycles of the symmetric permutation group $S_3$ the elements themselves rather than their reverses?

E.g. why is $(1,2)^{-1}=(1,2)$ and not $(2,1)$?

Comment: $(1,2) = (2, 1)$.

Comment: $(1,2)$ is the function that interchanges $1$ and $2$; so is $(2,1)$. Thus, $(1,2)=(2,1)$.

Comment: Also it is not true that inverses of elements in $S_3$ are the elements themselves! For example the inverse of the cycle $(123)$ is $(132) = (321)$, which is different from $(123)$.

Comment: Hi, have you received a satisfactory answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\sigma$ be a permutation. Now $(1,2)$ means that $$\sigma(1)=2, \sigma(2)=1$$ Then inverse $(1,2)^{-1}=(2,1)$ Now by the above permutation $$\sigma(2)=1,\sigma(1)=2$$So $(2,1)=(1,2)$ and so the inverse remains the same

Answer (score 1):

First, note that for a 2-cycle we will always have $(a,b)^{-1}=(a,b)$, because the permutation $(a,b)$ is only exchanging the positions of $a$ and $b$, and by doing this process twice you will get to the initial position again.

On the other hand, it is not true that in $S_3$ the inverses of the elements are the elements them selves. For instance:

$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\ 2 & 3 & 1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\ 3 & 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}\neq \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\ 2 & 3 & 1\end{pmatrix}$